# How to build this GUI effect in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface

I am new to Java and I want to make a small game like 
http://www.oopixel.com/games/samegame/
and I want to make same effect  like in Yellow box [image]

My question is from where should be star because I do not know the name of this to look for it

Please help me I have spent hours on this, but I did not get anything

Comment: Where should you start?  Look up examples, code, and *tinker*.  This isn't a great question, but you should be prepared to go forth and experiment on something like this.

Comment: My problem I do not know this characterization to start search for it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own version of the game using instances of `JToggleButton` in a `GridLayout`, as shown [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/buttons). The yellow rectangle could be drawn on the [glass pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html#glasspane) using `drawRect()` with a `Stroke` of `4`. The `+15` looks a lot like a [tool tip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html), as @informatik01 suggests. See also this simple [`MVCGame`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).

Comment: I can not express how grateful you.Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You can read in JOGL ,it is a wrapper library that allows OpenGL to be used in the Java programming language

Answer (score 2):

Well, seems like a **tool tip** here if you are talking about "+15" on the blue background in the yellow box.

Here is the official Oracle Java Swing tutorial and tool tip example:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html

Comment: +1 for [tool tip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html).